# WebView not show content properly in android

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

In android, Webview not show proper UI but in **browser** it's working fine.

what is the issue with it?
why not show content in full width?
thanks in advance

I have added  [code of page.](https://expirebox.com/download/953f26e07f14c5e57c993f7b53ad7312.html)

[image][image]

Comment: My guess is that your web page is not responsive.

Comment: but why  size change of text?

Comment: please post your code here and don't upload it into external sites

Comment: u need to talk with web designer for this issue bcz u cant do anything ..

Comment: that's fine but why content resize?

Answer (score 0):

Don't just use webview. also set it to run all functionalities like browsers.

---

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

---

.goBack() allows going back in webview. 
..... There are many properties you have to set, if you want it to look like browser and responsive

Answer (score 0):

Did you have this in the header of the HTML?

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```